# Coderay alternative in Scala which gives formatted and syntax highlighted code

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Coderay is a nice gem available in ruby which gives formatted and syntax highlighted code and it supports 20 plus languages. Is there any alternative in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean *hightlighter which supports scala* you can give [prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) a shot. In fact it is the prettifier that stackoverflow uses, and result you may seen below:

```
object Hello extends App { 
  println("Hello world!")
}
```

There is also [pygments which supports scala as well](http://pygments.org/languages/). If you want similar functionality **written** in scala, I think you will find none.

Comment: Is there an alternative written in Java? It would be usable from Scala.

Comment: `syntaxhighlighter` seems perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is anything like that written in java.

However you could try to make a jar from coderay with jruby. If you succeed you could use it in play.

However, this is just an idea. Never have I done or tried it.

You can check how Asciidoctor made their port to Java. They allow using coderay as syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I am using `syntaxhighlighter`. The code indentation is not supported (this is possible in Coderay) but syntax highlighting is working perfectly for all popular programming languages. This tutorial helped me. 
Thanks to **alexgorbatchev** for developing such a wonderful application.
I am giving the details here.
http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Steps:-

1) Add this two lines in your build.sbt.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.webjars" % "syntaxhighlighter" % "3.0.83"
```

2) Run sbt
3) Configure routes

```
GET     /webjars/*file             controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

4) Edit main.scala and include the required `CSS` and `JavaScript` files.

Comment: Cool,  Syntax Highlighter is a good product. I never would have thought to use SBT to download it, plus adding to the 'route' file.  Nice touch!   Dumping the file(s) in the /public folder would have been a working but, much poorer solution.